# How to secure asp.net mvc5 applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

```
<authentication mode="Forms"/>
 <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" defaultUrl="~/Login/Something" protection="All"></forms>
</authentication>
```

One way is to add Authorization tag to every Controller to secure application from unauthorized user.Other way is to use session variables to store user information .So,my question is from hacking perspective,how we can secure our application form hackers?Is there any other way to secure application?

Comment: Yes, adding [Authorize] to all controllers is the way to secure them. What are you asking? If there are others options? But why - is [Authorize] not fitting your needss? We need some more information.

Comment: [Authorize] tag fulfilling my needs.But i am talking about Enterprise level application perspective .How can we add more security to our application?  Is [Authorize] is the only way to secure application?.

Comment: the `[Authorize]` annotation will check against unauthenticated requests on the controller/action that it is on as well as check that a user is in a given role. As far as applicaton code goes, there are many other ways hackers can gain access to or exploit your applications (sql injection, XSS, etc) Completely protecting your application from hackers in any live, hosted environment is a much bigger topic than securing application code. I think we need more specifics on what exactly you're looking at securing or else the answer to this will be multiple entire books

Comment: What is "more security"?

Comment: If the answer to this post was simple enough to fit in a stackoverflow answer, then penetration testing would not be a field :) my advice would be: read. read. read some more. If you're not familiar with best practices in application code security and networking infrastructure security then I'd advise reaching out to a third party pen testing company if this application holds sensitive data

Comment: Yes, Thanks, #JLe, and #GregH.
I mean I know some method like using Anti-Foreigners, and I have my business logic in the separate class library project. But I just want to know more about securing my web-application. Like there is an application JMeter that sends millions of request to the server and decrease performance or how to disable any IP how is trying to exploit using Burp-Suite etc application.

Comment: @JLe more security means to increase the security level. Basically, I am simply using form authentication by adding the [authorize] tag and session variables. I know by using this my application is still on the initial stage of security which is not a good sign. Because nowadays security is the major concern of any application.its only for building the trust level of our valuable client. That's the only reason am asking about this because I don't want to go for a third party security which is highly paid.

Comment: "I know by using this my application is still on the initial stage of security which is not a good sign" - what? Yes, as far as it is only secured in the user-has-logged-in kind of way, but are you not satisfied with the protection the Forms authentication brings? But then, as @GregH points out, you need to make sure other parts of your application is safe, that is, input data validation, XSS, SQL Injection if necessary, protection user data and sensitive data etc. You need to be more specific I'm afraid.

Comment: "I know by using this my application is still on the initial stage of security which is not a good sign".Its mean that doesn't rely on this and say my application is secure. According to you, we should have to introduce custom header in the web.config file, means Enable X-XSS-Protection to prevent from XXS Attack. Thanks a lot, @JLe for your valuable time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** This answer should not be viewed as complete in any way, security is always hard and if it's important to you - always consult with a third party security and penetration testing company. This is just a few things you should consider to make your MVC application safer (not necessarily safe).

#### Protect controllers

First step is to apply `[Authorize]` to your controllers, to make sure there is some sort of valid authentication before accessing a method. Preferably add `Authorize` to all controllers and make exceptions with `[AllowAnonymous]` to make it secure-by-default.

#### Authorize the user

Even though you've added `[Authorize]` to the controller, that only means that the user is logged in, not that the user should have access to whatever method is being accessed. The first step is to extend the attribute by specifying a set of roles for the method: `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator"]`

Depending on the application, you might also have to check that the current user belongs to the company/group or whatever that is being edited, to prevent someone from modifying data that doesn't belong to them.

#### Don't leak data into models

If you're using your actual data models as view models, you are at risk of allowing the user to enter more data than they're supposed to. Consider this example:

```
class Employee {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Assume that we for some reason allow our employees to change their name, and we use the `Employee` model for that. But of course we only make an edit field for the `Name`, and not the `Salary` as that would be stupid :D. However, due to how the model-binding works, a smart Employee could just add `<input type="text" name="Salary" value="2147483647">` to the form when changing their name, and our gullible `db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Added;` followed by `db.SaveChanges()` would update their salary as well.

Solution? Either make a view model with only the `Id` and `Name` property, to make it impossible to change the salary, or use the `Bind` attribute to only include the properties we allow: `public IActionResult Update([Bind(Include="Id,Name")]Employee model)`.

#### XSS

A very important part is to protect your users from bad dynamic content. If I can enter HTML and Javascript that's displayed to some other user, I can abuse that to steal their authentication token for example. Making to never render user-entered data as HTML is a first step to prevent this. You should also make sure to always use the anti-forgery token in your forms as well. Adding CSP headers is a good practice to prevent someone from injecting scripts that shouldn't be there.